# Csh echo foreach loop index

Tags: linux, shell, foreach, csh

Hi I'm new to shell scripting in csh and I need help with an annoying problem. Take the code below:

```
   set s = ("one" "two" "three" "four")
   foreach i (${s})
      echo $i"-" [what do I put here to get the index?]
   end
```

This yields the output

```
  one-
  two-
  three-
  four-
```

However, I would also like to print out the loop counter index too, so:

```
  one-1
  two-2
  three-3
  four-4
```

Sorry if this question is really basic but I don't have much experience in shell scripting (let alone csh) and forums and other stack-overflow posts didn't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a separate variable which you manually increment:

```
set s = ("one" "two" "three" "four")
set i = 0
foreach v ( $s )
    echo "$v - $i"
    @ i = $i + 1

    # Also works
    #@ i++
end
```

You can do arithmetic by using the special `@` command (the space between `@` and `i` is *mandatory* since this is a command, and not "syntax", you can actually use *any* expression here, not just arithmetic).

Since `i` (for "iteration") is sort-of the standard name for this, I renamed your `$i` to `$v` for "value".

As a final note, you probably don't want to use `csh` for scripting if it can be avoided. It has many problems and limitations.

Answer (score 0):

For var in One-1 Two-2 Three-3 Four-4

do

echo $var

done

Comment: Shubh Patel, while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.